# unwanted indent following newly defined environment (equation)

Tags: environments

I define a new environment named `myequation` (later I would like to taylor it to my needs). I can use it the same way as the original `equation` environment, except that the text following `\end{myequation}` begins with an unwanted leading space. I can remove this unwanted space by writing `\end{myequation}%` instead of just `\end{myequation}`. In the following code equation (2) and (3) were produced using `myequation`. I would like to have a definition where there is no need for this trailing percentage sign (in case I forget it).

My example LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myequation}{\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}}
\setlength{\textwidth}{10em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
III III III III III III
III III III III III III
\begin{equation}\alpha\beta\alpha\beta\alpha\beta\end{equation}
III III III III III III
III III III III III III
\begin{myequation}\alpha\beta\alpha\beta\alpha\beta\end{myequation}
% unwanted indentation here because of missing % after \end{myequation}
III III III III III III
III III III III III III
\begin{myequation}\alpha\beta\alpha\beta\alpha\beta\end{myequation}%
III III III III III III
III III III III III III
\end{document}
```

Is there a solution (ideally without having to load an additional package)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\newenvironment{myequation}
 {\begin{equation}}
 {\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
```

Comment: `\ignorespacesafterend`  did the trick. Thank you!